# Ansible: Running a single play on a single host more than a single time

Tags: ansible

I would like to distribute some ansible deployment scripts where a customer only needs to describe their infrastructure and place some important values into an inventory file. On occasion, a single role may need to be applied to a single host more than one time.  In order to keep the customer from having to make modifications to the playbook itself, I would like for them to be able to describe the infrastructure similar to the following:

**inventory_file**

```
[servers:children]
servers-a
servers-b

[servers-a]
host1 server_port=1337

[servers-b]
host1 server_port=1335
```

**playbook.yml**:

```
---

- name: Set up Servers
  hosts: servers
  roles:
    - role: server_setup
```

I'm aware of the **allow_duplicates** meta value for a role and it is enabled for the example 'servers' role. It appears that the role will only be applied once with the above playbook and with the latter defined variable.

I know of one solution, which would be to create additional hostname aliases for the host.

Is anyone familiar with a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, sometimes `server_port` value should be `1335` or `1337`.

I would not recommend creating an inventory in such a way, as it misleading. 
If the value of server port is always `1335` or `1337`, I would configure a default value in `server_setup` under `defaults\main.yml`:

```
# server_setup\defaults\main.yml
server_port: 1335
```

If any other value should be configured the playbook can be executed as follows:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --limit=host1 --extra-vars "server_port=1337"
```

In this case the customer can run the playbook as many times as needed.

Comment: The question I'm asking is how to apply the role to the server twice, using two different port numbers, regardless of what the default is.